# Getting url data from php file to another where it is being loaded into via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm just playing around with a user profile page which gets data from the url to load specific content by user e.g.UserProfiles.php?user=jay101.

I've got a separate file which has been loaded in by ajax which retrieves other information about that specific user

```
   var loadContent = function() {
   $('.commentContainer').load('userProfileComments.php');
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        loadContent();
        setInterval(loadContent, 10000);

    });
```

The file that is loaded into the userProfile.php (userProfileComments.php) and requires the $_GET['user'] that is used by the userProfile.php to retrieve information about the user using mysqli.

How do I send the $_GET['user'] to the userProfileComments.php so it is able to retrieve information about the user?

thanks

Comment: Why not you load it as `$('.commentContainer').load('userProfileComments.php?user=jay101');`?

Comment: I just face palmed

Comment: @Viswalinga Surya S I don't know why I didn't just put the get in the load url haha, thanks!

Comment: :D Glad you learnt a new thing!